# Why i get can not resolve method error in class android?

Tags: android, json

I use this tutorial:

[JSON](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/)

and part of code to this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            TextView lbl=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.provCODE);
            person = new Person();
            person.setName(lbl.getText().toString());
            //person.setCountry("1853");
            //person.setTwitter("1892");


            return POST(urls[0],person);
        }
```

but in the this line:

```
person.setName(lbl.getText().toString());
```

i get this error:

```
Can not resolve method.
```

How can i solve that?what happen?
my person class is:

```
public class Person {

        private String name;
        private String country;
        private String twitter;

//getters & setters....

    }
```

Comment: Post your Person class.

Comment: do you have `setName` in Person ? Is it public ?

Comment: @Blackbelt i follow step by step up tutorial link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't create setName() method in Person class.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String twitter;

    //getters & setters....
    public void setName(String pName) {
        this.name = pName;
    }

    public void getName() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: But up tutorial so do not write that method?how can i write setName method?

Comment: How can i add getName method?

Comment: Updated my answer. Accept it if it works for you. Also, I think you need to learn Java first.